Saturation properties of magnetic steels
While permeability properties of ferritic steels are (sometimes) detailed in sellers' information pages, I never found data on magnetic saturation of steels. As I am looking for materials which are effective in interfering with always-on magnetic fields, to me saturation is more important than permeability. I wonder, are saturation data part of AISI 400 series standards? or at least are there any firms who has done specific material's tests?

Published specifications included magnetic saturation when I was working with transformers. Maybe you should look for steel specified for that use.

Some pertinent data might be found from motor lamination suppliers. Laminations come in a variety of thicknesses and are alloyed for good magnetic properties.

Magnetic saturation relies more on specialized applications and is not typically a standardized property in specifications like the AISI 400 series standards. If I remember correctly, these standards are more focused on mechanical and chemical properties. I would contact the supplier for more details. They may be able to provide specific information on your application.

Since magnetic permeability tells you how much a material will channel the external magnetic field's field lines, I believe magnetic permeability + wall thickness of the "blocking" material is all that is needed.
The actual calculation to get thickness needed to block some input field seems complicated since the input field is also varying radially, but to do this experimentally, just pick a material with high permeability and some thickness.
Place it in your field "blocking" application, and see whether any field has penetrated to the "shielded' side (with a piece of iron, for example).  If the field is still too high for your application, either increase thickness (eg. stack a 2nd blocking wall) or find a material with higher permeability, or both.
